# How to add the google map in the listview to show every record's location

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I want to add the google map on every list/record on listview .The latitude and longitude is fetched from the database .Pass the lat lng to the to google map to get the location on the google map .As per clicked on the direction button ,the it should have to show the google map .Here is my code .....

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:data/dbHelper.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class showOutlets extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<showOutlets> createState() => showOutletsState();
}
class showOutletsState extends State<showOutlets> {
  SQLHelper db = SQLHelper();
  late GoogleMapController mapController;


      
    List LatLng=  [];      ** // Longitude and latitude is fetched from the database in the list/map**

  List outlets = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;
  initState(){
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((onvalue) async{
      LatLng=await db.getLatLng();
      print("type-->${LatLng}");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

    });
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((onvalue) async {
      outlets = await db.getOutletsData();
      print("type-->${outlets}");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      filterController.addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          filter = filterController.text;
        });
      });
    });
  }
  static  var boldStyle= const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );
  String? filter;
  TextEditingController filterController = new TextEditingController();
  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: outlets == null ? 0 : outlets.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          if (filter == null || filter == "") {
            return new ListTile(

**              //Here I want to pass the google map widget  which contains the 
               //longitude and latitude from the map data  in the trailing:IconButton **
                 
              title: new Text(outlets[i]['OutletID']+" - "+outlets[i]['OutletName']),
              subtitle: new Text("Phone#: "+outlets[i]['Telephone']+"\nAddress: "+outlets[i]['Address']),
              trailing:   new IconButton(onPressed: null, icon:Icon(Icons.directions,color: Colors.blue,)),

            );
          } else {
            if (outlets[i]['OutletName'].toLowerCase().contains(filter..toString().toLowerCase()) || outlets[i]['OutletID'].toLowerCase().contains(filter.toString().toLowerCase())) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(outlets[i]['OutletID']+" - "+outlets[i]['OutletName']),
                subtitle: new Text("Phone#: "+outlets[i]['Telephone']+"\nAddress: "+outlets[i]['Address']),
                trailing:    IconButton(onPressed: null, icon:Icon(Icons.directions,color: Colors.blue,)),

              );

            } else {
              return new Container();
            }
          }

        });
  }

 // googleMap(){
 //    return  GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition:new CameraPosition(
 //      target: LatLng,
 //      zoom: 11.0,
 //    ));
 //
 // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:  const Text('User Data' ),

        ),
        body:_isLoading == false? const Center(

          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ):
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding:   EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      style:   TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon:  Icon(Icons.search),
                        hintText: "Search Customers...",
                      ),
                      controller: filterController,
                    )),
                Expanded(
                  child:  Padding(
                      padding:   EdgeInsets.only(top: 05.0),
                      child: _buildListView()
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use Fixed height for maps and use just listview

Comment: Did u solve this? if yes can u share the code??

Comment: @Mr.Robot you can simply add an icon (icons. direction ) in every record of the list and launch the google map by this method => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75097664/flutter-map-polyline-bug-there-is-a-line-in-the-map-super-frustrating/75105685#75105685